# user input .txt file search C

Tags: c, file-io

I'm trying to make a program that accepts user input and searches all matching results in a .csv file. What I want to do is to output all the strings in the .csv file that match the user's search. Right now it prompts the user to enter a search but the output is always the same no matter what string is entered.

This is my code so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
    FILE *fp=fopen("file.csv","r+");
    char  buf[1000];
    char  str[25];

    printf("Enter your search:");
    scanf ("%s", str);

    while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf),fp)!= NULL)
    {
        if (strstr(buf, "str")){
            printf("%s\n", buf);
        }    
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, currently you're only searching for `"Salmon"`, not the user's input.

In any case, you have specified invalid flags for the file open mode...

If you want to read AND write to the file, use `"r+"`, `"w+"` or `"a+"`.

If you just want to read, use the mode `"r"`.

Comment: thanks for the reply, if I only want to search for the string entered by the user in the .csv file, i don't need a write flag right? If I use the r+ flag I get the same error..

Comment: That's correct -- you just want to read the file.  You are not going to modify it.  Probably it's failing to open with write access because you have it open in an editor.

Comment: You mean i have the .csv file open while trying to read it? But i don't

Comment: It was just a hunch.  Maybe it's read-only.  Anyway, the rule is: just *don't* open with write-access if you don't want to change the file.

Comment: Ok, I figured it was a problem with my compiler. Because it does compile on Xcode, however, when I enter a search I get "Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”. "  Any idea why?

Comment: Did you change the open mode to just `"r"`?

Comment: Yeah just "r". It's working now but no matter what string I enter for the search it will always output the same results.

Comment: Would that by any chance be lines that contain the word "Salmon"?

Comment: Yeah, I updated the code above but still shows the same results. Thanks for the help paddy.

Comment: I gave you all the information you needed in my original answer, and sort of got the impression you didn't take it in.  If you want to search for the value that the user entered in `str` instead of the string `"Salmon"` then pass `str` into the `strstr()` call instead!!

Comment: Yeah I am passing str into the strstr() call but it doesn't match the value entered in str.

Comment: Pass it without the quotes.  It is a variable.  If you use the quotes then you are looking for lines that contain the text "str".  Without the quotes, you are looking for the string that is stored in the variable named `str`.

Answer (score 1):

In your latest edit, the code has double-quotes around the str variable that need to be removed

```
if (strstr(buf, "str")){
```

should be

```
if (strstr(buf, str)){
```

Comment: Yeah my bad, but still it won't return the results matching str.

Answer (score 0):

In case of .csv file. It would be great if you could open it in "r+" mode.
In your case it should be like.

```
FILE *fp=fopen("file.csv","r+");
```

Both r+ and w+ we can read ,write on file but r+ does not truncate  (delete) the content of file  as well it doesn’t create a new file if such file doesn’t exits while in w+ truncate the content of file as well as create a new file if such file doesn’t exists